# How to sort both the content inside the group and the whole data in SSRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How to group the list in the page in SSRS. I have person_last_name,person_first_name,person_id,email_addres in my table. I need to do sort the list in the SSRS report.

In my report I have grouped with person_last_name and to sort the data I have used the sort property in the tablix properties. The data on the whole is sorted when I selected "Details" option. Then I tried to sort the content inside the grouped item  that was also successful. How can I sort both the content inside the group and the whole data.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a Teacher with students and you want to sort the teachers by last name and the students by last name up or down. You would need to add a sort to you top level group, in this case teacher, and also to the detail group the sort expressions can be set independently.